# In memcached persistent connection or per request

Tags: node.js, performance, caching, memcached

In my application written in nodejs I want to use memcached. Traffic will be more or less 215k visits per day. In cache will be only one key.

My question is:
Should I establish connection per each request or maybe do it once for whole life of app?

Answer (score 0):

Persistent connection should be better in case of huge load, it's always saving some time on connecting / etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a npm package to do that, so you don't have to mind on these stuff.
Something like:

- [3rd-Eden/node-memcached](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached),
- [elbart/node-memcache](https://github.com/elbart/node-memcache) or
- [overclocked/mc](https://github.com/overclocked/mc)

Will do the job. Check on each one of those project about the configuration that you can customize to get different results.
Hope this helps!

Comment: This modules allow to make connections with memcache - that's true. Let's pick `node-memcached`. Now with this module I should execute this code: `var memcached = new Memcached(Server locations, options);` only once somewhere in `app.js` or per request?

Comment: do it only once make a single object once in app.js and use it every where. That's the trick.

Comment: As @Vickrant said, you should do it just only once on you application, and use always the same instance, so you don't generate distinct instances with different connections. That's it :)